# Vulkan: What is the point of sType in vk*CreateInfo structs?

Tags: c, specifications, vulkan

In all of the create info structs (`vk*CreateInfo`) in the new Vulkan API, there is ALWAYS a `.sType` member. Why is this there if the value can only be one thing? Also the Vulkan specification is very explicit that you can only use `vk*CreateInfo` structs as parameters for their corresponding `vkCreate*` function. It seems a little redundant. I can see that if the driver was passing this struct straight to the GPU, you might need to have it (I did notice it is always the first member). But this seems like a really bad idea for the app to do it because if the driver did it, apps would be much less error prone, and prepending an int to a struct doesn't seems like an extremely computational inefficient operation. I just don't see why it exists.

TL;DR 
    Why do the `vk*CreateInfo` structs have the `.sType` member?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

They have one so that the `pNext` field actually works.

Yes, the API takes a struct with a proper C type, so both the caller and the receiver agree on what type that struct is. But especially nowadays, many such structs have linked lists of structures that provide additional information to the implementation. These extension structures (though many are core in Vulkan 1.1/2) are just like all other structures, with their own `sType` field.

These fields are crucial because the linked lists are built with `pNext` pointers... which are `void*`s. They have no set type. The way the implementation determines what a non-NULL `pNext` pointer points to is by examining the first 4 bytes stored there. This is the `sType` field; it allows the implementation to know what type to cast the pointer to.

Of course, the primary struct that an API takes doesn't strictly need an `sType` field, since its type is part of the API itself. However, there is a hypothetical reason to do so (it hasn't panned out in Vulkan releases).

A later version of Vulkan could expand on the creation of, for example, command buffer pools. But how would it do that? Well, they could add a whole new entrypoint: `vkCreateCommandPool2`. But this function would have almost the exact same signature as `vkCreateCommandPool`; the only difference is that they take different `pCreateInfo` structures.

So instead, all you have to do is declare a `VkCommandPoolCreateInfo2` structure. And then declare that `vkCreateCommandPool` can take either one. How would the implementation tell which one you passed in?

Because the first 4 bytes of any such structure is `sType`. They can test that value. If the value is `VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_POOL_CREATE_INFO`, then it's the old structure. If it's `VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_POOL_CREATE_INFO_2`, then it's the new one.

Of course, as previously stated, this hasn't panned out; post-1.0 Vulkan versions opted to incorporate extension structs rather than replacing existing ones. But the option is there.

Comment: Why wouldn't a hypothetical 1.1 SDK release only contain the updated `vkCreateCommandBufferPool()` definition with the updated signature? Most libraries don't contain all of the different revisions of their structures from throughout their version history. Why would a library like Vulkan do it? Or are libraries like that unique because an application maybe need to resort to an older structure depending on the capabilities of the hardware?

Comment: @spaaarky21: Because they promised not to. Vulkan's specification lays out how versioning works. It spells out what changes they will make for which kind of version changes. Minor version changes are specified to be backwards compatible with all lower minor versions from the same major version. So if I write code against 1.0, it will work on an 1.1 or 1.2 implementation. But there is no guarantee that it will work on 2.0 or 3.0.