# Purpose of pNext in Vulkan structures

Tags: vulkan

A lot of the structures used in Vulkan have a *sType* member, which identifies the type of the structure, and a *pNext* member, for extension-specific structures. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36347301/2363967) explains quite well what the *sType* member is for, and why it is needed. It briefly touches on *pNext*, although I'm not sure I understand the rationale behind it.

If the first member of every structure is *sType*, couldn't extensions just define their own structure types when they need different/extra parameters?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As clearly stated in the specification:

> Any parameter that is a structure containing a `void*` `pNext` member must have a value of `pNext` that is either `NULL`, or points to a valid structure that is defined by an enabled extension.

It's for extensions.

> If the first member of every structure is sType, couldn't extensions just define their own structure types when they need different/extra parameters?

That wouldn't be extensible.

There is only one `sType` field. So how could two extensions extend the same API with new values? Similarly, how could an old extension work alongside new versions of Vulkan that itself uses a different data structure identified by `sType`.

With `pNext`, you don't have that problem. Each extension data structure will not only have its own internal `sType` field, but it will no doubt also have its own `pNext` field. So multiple extensions can extend the same data structures.

`sType` doesn't need this, because it will only be changed in higher versions of Vulkan.

Comment: Oh, so if every extension structure starts with sType and pNext, you can have a linked list of extension-specific data?

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson: I thought the name `pNext` made that rather obvious.

Comment: Yeah, every time I ask a question and you answer it, I feel a bit more like an idiot...

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm ready to sound like a complete doofus, but I've always wondered what the `p` and the `pp` at the beginning of some struct memebers stood for in Vulkan. (I assume that the `s` here stands for struct/structure)

Comment: @OnaFriday p for pointer, and pp for pointer to pointer(s). You can add as many 'p's as you need for the corresponding levels of pointer indirection.

Comment: @Jerfov2 This is [Hungarian notation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation), a sort of inline type documentation used, for example, throughout the Win32 API. Whether it is a good idea is another question.