# Why do some struct types let us set members that can only be a certain value?

Tags: struct, types, vulkan

I was reading up on some vulkan struct types, this is one of many examples, but the one I will use is vkInstanceCreateInfo. The documentation states:

> The VkInstanceCreateInfo structure is defined as:

```
typedef struct VkInstanceCreateInfo {
    VkStructureType             sType;
    const void*                 pNext;
    VkInstanceCreateFlags       flags;
    const VkApplicationInfo*    pApplicationInfo;
    uint32_t                    enabledLayerCount;
    const char* const*          ppEnabledLayerNames;
    uint32_t                    enabledExtensionCount;
    const char* const*          ppEnabledExtensionNames;
} VkInstanceCreateInfo;
```

Then below in the options we see:

> sType is the type of this structure
>
> sType **must** be VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO

If we dont have any options anyway, why is this parameter not just set implicitly upon creation of the type?

Note: I realise this is not something specific to the vulkan API.

Update: I'm not just talking specifically about vulkan, just all parameters that can only be a certain type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vulkan: What is the point of sType in vk\*CreateInfo structs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36347236/vulkan-what-is-the-point-of-stype-in-vkcreateinfo-structs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The design allows structures to be chained together so that extensions can create additional parameters to existing calls without interfering with the original API structures and without interfering with each other.

Nearly *every* struct in Vulkan has `sType` as it's first member, and `pNext` as it's second member.  That means that if you have a `void*` and all you know is that it is some kind of Vulkan API struct, you can safely read the first 32 bits and it will be a `VkStructureType` and read the next 32 or 64 bits and it will tell you if there's another structure in the chain.

So for instance, there's a `VkMemoryAllocateInfo` structure for allocating memory that has (aside from `sType` and `pNext` the size of the allocation and the heap index it should come from.  But what if I want to use the "dedicated allocation" extension.  Then I also need to fill out a `VkMemoryDedicatedAllocateInfo` structure with extra information.  But I still need to call the same `vkAllocateMemory` function that only takes a `VkMemoryAllocateInfo`... so where do I put the `VkMemoryDedicatedAllocateInfo` structure I filled out?  I put a pointer to it in the `pNext` field of `VkMemoryAllocateInfo`.

Maybe I also want to share this memory with some OpenGL code.  There's an extension that lets you do that, but you need to fill out a `VkExportMemoryAllocateInfo` structure and pass it in during the allocation as well.  Well, I can do that by putting it in the `pNext` field of my `VkMemoryDedicatedAllocateInfo` structure.  I can create a chain of structures like that as long as I want.

Here's the really important part.  Since all structures have `sType` as their first field, an extension can navigate along this chain of structures and find the ones it cares about without knowing anything about the structures other than that they always start with `sType` and `pNext`.

All of this means that Vulkan can be extended in ways that alter the behavior of existing functions, but without changing the function itself, or the structures that are passed to it.

You might ask why all of the core structures have `sType` and `pNext`, even though you're passing them to functions with typed pointers, rather than void pointers.  The reason is consistency, and because you never know when an existing structure might be needed as part of the chain for some new extension.

> If we dont have any options anyway, why is this parameter not just set implicitly upon creation of the type?

Because C isn't C++.  There's no way to declare a structure in C and say that this portion of the structure will always have this value.  In C++ you can, by declaring something as const and providing the initial default value.  In fact, one of the things I like about the Vulkan C++ bindings is that you can basically forget about `sType` forever.  If you're using extensions you still need to populate `pNext` as appropriate.